# font stroke contrast is rendering badly in browser

Tags: typography, contrast, browser

I'm using `Tahoma` font in my site. I'm using all the css settings like `text-rendering` `-webkit-font-smoothing` to ensure that my font renders properly in browsers.

The only thing is the stroke contrast of the typeface is rendering badly in browsers (tested in mac - chrome, firefox & safari).

Text in *Photoshop* looks like this. Observe the letters 'I', 'T', 'P' especially bold letters. The stroke contrast looks very beautiful here.
[image: photoshop text]

This is the how *browser* renders. Looks very bad.

[image]

Is there any way that I can fix this issue. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using a separate bold font file for the bold text? Or are you letting the browser do it? The browser can only approximate bold fonts

Comment: I'm having bold face too. I have fonts installed in my machine. Even the normal font renders the stroke contrast differently if you observe them closely.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?? the 2nd one clearly looks smoothed (and better)

Comment: In Photoshop your image is handled like a photo/picture. The rasterisation is done by Photoshop. In a browser the (system) font render technique kicks in (and the color profile is turned off). Now redering should look like what you would see in other programmes that treat text as text and not as a photo. So render engines are different and give you different results. This is true for both regular and bold. But the bold has another trouble. It's not a true one. It is a 'faux bold' (Google that ;)).

Comment: I know about 'faux bold' and I'm sure that I use original bold face, not faux bold! It misses the stroke contrast in the curves of the letters. It is not as clean and sharp as photoshop rendered one. That is what my issue. I just want to know weather I can fix this

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time in the 90's I heard from a client --"How come the type on the web site doesn't look the same as it did in the Photoshop mockup?" . . .  I'd have some nickels. - Two different rendering engines. You can't make one engine run like another. This is why it is sometimes better to design in a browser rather than creating a full page mockup in other software.

Comment: So there is  no way to render the fonts in browsers perfectly, right? hmm.. hope browsers would get much better in future :(

Comment: Maybe if you provided a minimal example in html/CSS we could try to help, but as is this is impossible to answer